# If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^p,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|b_n|^p $ converge then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n+b_n|^p$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

For a real $p\geq 1$, why if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|a_n\right|^p,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|b_n\right|^p $ converge then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|a_n+b_n\right|^p$ converges?
I've tried using the fact that $f(x)=x^p$ is convex, to conclude something helpful, but failed.

Answer (score 6):

By [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality),
$$
\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k + b_k|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \le \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty |b_k|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
for $p\ge1$.

Answer (score 6):

By convexity of $x\mapsto x^p$ on the non-negative real line, 
$$\left|\frac{a_n+b_n}2\right|^p\leqslant \frac 12\left|a_n\right|^p+\frac 12\left|b_n\right|^p,$$
which gives $\left|a_n+b_n\right|^p\leqslant 2^{p-1}\left(\left|a_n\right|^p+\left|a_n\right|^p\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's also true for $0<p<1: $ If $a,b\ge 0,$ then $(a+b)^p \le a^p+b^p.$

Comment: Good observation. It would be nice to include a proof. One way is to recognize that if $0< p < 1$, then $x \mapsto x^p$ is concave for nonnegative $x$, and any concave function $f$ satisfying $f(0) \geq 0$ is subadditive: $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$. [Simple two-line proof (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Properties) - item 10 under "Properties"